# How to inject a dll to a another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dll-injection

I have been trying for the last few days to create a DLL injector.
The simplest method I found for DLL injection is using `CreateRemoteThread`

This is what I have written so far, this code doesn't work and cannot find out why.

I am pretty sure that my problem is in the variables types I am using to call the WinAPI functions but I cannot find where.

```
bool Injector::Inject( HANDLE hProcess )
{
    //hProcess is a process with writing and reading access
    HANDLE hThread;
    void*  pLibRemote = 0;  
    string dllPath = "Some dll path";
    HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle(__TEXT("Kernel32"));


    pLibRemote = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(dllPath.c_str()), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pLibRemote, dllPath.c_str(), sizeof(dllPath.c_str()), NULL);

    hThread = CreateRemoteThread( hProcess, NULL, 0,    
                    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ::GetProcAddress(hKernel32,"LoadLibraryA"), 
                    pLibRemote, 0, NULL );


    .
    .
    .

    CloseHandle(hThread);

    }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least 2 problems :

```
pLibRemote = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(dllPath.c_str()), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

1) `sizeof(dllPath.c_str())` : you are doing sizeof on a pointer ([c_str() returns a pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)), hence you'll probably get 4 or 8 as a result. Use `dllPath.size() + sizeof(char)` (or `wchar_t` instead of `char` if using `std::wstring`).

2) Use `MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT` instead of just `MEM_COMMIT` : you want to reserve **and** commit the reserved memory at the same time.

Also ensure both programs use the same ISA (x86 / x86 ; x64 / x64, but not a mismatched ISA).

Comment: That worked! thank you very much! can you please explain to me why did you use `dllPath.size() + sizeof(char)` instead of just `dllPath.size()` (is that because of the null terminator?)

Comment: @HackinGuy Exactly, [string::size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) will return the number of characters, excluding the terminating NULL. Coming to think of it, the string size **in bytes** should be calculated as: `(string.size() * sizeof(TCHAR)) + sizeof(TCHAR)`, so this works if you are using std::string with char and std::wstring with wchar_t and _UNICODE is defined.

Comment: @Neitsa you can't use `sizeof(TCHAR)` unless you also use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` to match. `std::string` uses `char`, `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t`. Use appropriate Ansi/Unicode APIs accordingly (`LoadLibraryA`/`LoadLibraryW`). In this case, `std::string` is being used, so use `(string.size()+1) * sizeof(char)`.